# MonoTouch: PresentModalViewController and PresentViewController

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

Using MonoTouch 6

If we use **PresentViewController** instead of **PresentModalViewController**, will this work in iOS 5?

**PresentModalViewController** is depreciated in iOS 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will work with iOS 5, since `PresentViewController` was available with iOS 5.

I have an app that uses both because it is not complete yet and runs perfectly on both iOS versions. Since `PresentModalViewController` is deprecated with iOS 6, it would be a good practice to start replacing it.